# RAIDXpert2 LECACY array gone! What i should do?

Tags: raid, amd-ryzen

So big story short, i built a PC a few years ago and got a 14tb HDD to go with it. Since then i wanted to buy another one after i had the funds to make a RAID 1 array for redundancy.

I got the 2nd drive a few days ago and today i've installed it. Since i don't have another big drive to copy the data to temporarily in order to create the array and then copy it back i came up with a plan that should work in theory:

1. Install the 2nd drive and create a "RAIDable" array that will allow me to make a real array after i add at least one more drive
2. Copy the data from 1st drive to this array of 2nd drive
3. Add the 1st drive to the array to make it RAID 1, losing the data of 1st drive in the process

When i've installed the 2nd drive today i removed all the other ones. Inside the bios using the RAID menu it wouldn't give me the option to create an array since if i used the option to initialize the drive it didn't do anything. So there was no "RAIDable" option to be found anywhere.

So i decided to check what i can do with the software instead. At this time i put the 1st drive back in too.

Inside the RAIDxpert 2 software 1st time i've opened it it showed 2 arrays. One with the 1st drive shown as LECACY and one with the 2nd drive as VOLUME.

And here where my problem occurred. I clicked to initialize the 1st drive and it automatically deleted the LECACY array without asking and there is no option to bring it back. Now i have no access to my data.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Reverting back to AHCI with the 1st drive only it shows it totally messed up:

[image]

It was a single partition with about 7.5TB of data..

What i can do now?

I found this similar issue here: https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/accidental-hdd-array-deletion-raidxpert-array-recovery.2572332/

My guess is to create a new array, and make it RAID1 from this step but click "leave existing data"? Then how do i recover them?

Any help with be really appreciated. My system is based on AMD X570 chipset.

Kind regards

Comment: I hope you understand that RAID1 is not true redundancy, it makes you more resilient to data loss, but true redundancy only comes from having multiple backups.  "What i can do now?" - You can try using TestDisk and recovery the original partition table, but honestly, there is a very good chance the action was destructive which means you lost your data.

Comment: issue i think i messed up some more after. I created a new RAID 1 array after this happened and i clicked to leave existing data, and i deleted it immediately after that's why the partitions show weird in the 2nd photo..i use testdisk now in deepscan mode but it's really slow, it will take at least 10 full days to complete..and for now it gives me garbage output :/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QsBCyuk7